# jQuery resetting back css after spotlight

Tags: jquery, css, function

Im kindda new to jQuery so ill try my best to explain

So I have a spotlight script, inside it is a button. I managed to change the font size but when the user closes the spotlight the buttons font size is still the same size "500%". How can I change it back to the default font size?

Thank You

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#community-wrap .community-status').click(function(){
        jQuery("#community-wrap .community-status .button").css({"font-size":"500%"});
        jQuery(this).spotlight();

    });

});
```

Comment: If you're looking for the font-size to be changed back when you click on the button just try [ToggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: read the docs if there is a close event given by the plugin you can reset the css prop on close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the exit event and reset it yourself:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#community-wrap .community-status').click(function(){
        jQuery("#community-wrap .community-status .button").css({"font-size":"500%"});
        jQuery(this).spotlight({
             onHide: function(){
                 jQuery("#community-wrap .community-status .button").css({"font-size":"100%"});
             }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answer on your code also , how did you close the spotlight ?  if you are using jquery to close the following code will work to reset your button font-size

```
$.('.close').click(function(){
$("#community-wrap .community-status .button").css({"font-size":"put-your default size"});
}
```